Не могу прикрепить значок крестика на открытое фото
Попросил друг подшаманить сайт. Застрял на добавлении крестика закрытия. Ставится куда угодно, только не на открытое фото в окне. Подскажите что ни так делаю. Код такой:


/* Image */

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.image.avatar48 {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #f00;
}

.image.avatar48 img {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

.image.fit {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.image.featured {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

.image.left {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
}

.image.centered {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

.image.centered img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}


/* Item */

.item {
  box-shadow: 0 0.05em 0.15em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.item header {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.item header h3 {
  font-size: 1em;
}


/* Row */

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.close {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  --weight: 3px;
  --aa: 1px;
  /* anti-aliasing */
  --color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent calc(50% - var(--weight) - var(--aa)), var(--color) calc(50% - var(--weight)), var(--color) calc(50% + var(--weight)), transparent calc(50% + var(--weight) + var(--aa))), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent calc(50% - var(--weight) - var(--aa)), var(--color) calc(50% - var(--weight)), var(--color) calc(50% + var(--weight)), transparent calc(50% + var(--weight) + var(--aa)));
}
<!-- Portfolio1 -->
<section id="portfolio1" class="two">

  <div class="container">

    <header>
      <h2>Натяжные потолки</h2>
    </header>

    <p>Натяжные потолки - без стыков, швов и перепадов. Огромная палитра цветов и фактур.<br/> Наша команда профессионалов с многолетним стажем работы и огромным опытом - выполнит монтаж любой сложности в кратчайшие сроки. Использование профессионального
      инструмента обеспечивает чистый монтаж.<br/> Мы всегда готовы удивлять своих клиентов приятными скидками и акциями. Потолки Моло - это ваш правильный выбор.</p>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-4 col-12-mobile">

        <article class="item">

          <a href="images/foto102.jpg" class="image fit"><img src="images/foto102.jpg" alt="" /</a>

            <header>
              <h3>Световые линии зигзаг на натяжном потолке</h3>
            </header>
        </article>
        <article class="item">
          <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/foto101.jpg" alt="" /></a>
          <header>
            <h3>Трековое освещение на натяжном потолке</h3>
          </header>
        </article>
        <!--<article class="item">
                                        <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/foto107.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                        <header>
                                            <h3>Фото 7</h3>
                                        </header>
                                    </article>-->



Надо как то прикрепить этот блок к ссылке на фото:


<div class="close"></div>



Я какие только коды не применял. Крестик то сверху, то снизу вокруг не открытого фото. Меня смущает этот кусок :


class="image fit"



Когда перед ним что то ставишь, ломается рамка и фото в полный размер на пол сайт. Извините за сумбур, в этом деле любитель. Но уже дело принципа!)



Если правильно понял, то вы хотите что бы крестик был на изображении. Если да, то у крестика делаете position:absolute; а у родительского элемента position:relative; тогда сможете спозиционировать крестик внутри элемента. И код по подробнее попробуйте выложить, не очень понятно что где размещается и какие стили применяются.

А то что вы что то ставите перед классом естественно сломает все, ведь вы добавляете еще один класс к элементу или изменяете его

Добавил побольше кода. Может поможет в понимании.

еще уточняющий вопрос, это у вас всплывающее окно? Если да то скрипт нужен или оно на Css

Да на Css. Когда на фото нажимаешь оно на весь экран раскрывается.

тогда добавьте еще стили всплывашки

но суть сильно не поменяется родитель с position relative а дочерний с position absolute если только в всплывашке что то другого не значиться

Я думаю должно быть что то типа этого. Исправил с возможными моими домыслами


 /* Image */

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.image.avatar48 {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #f00;
}

.image.avatar48 img {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

.image.fit {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.image.featured {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

.image.left {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
}

.image.centered {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

.image.centered img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}


/* Item */

.item {
  box-shadow: 0 0.05em 0.15em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.item header {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.item header h3 {
  font-size: 1em;
}


/* Row */

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.close {
  
  position: absolute;/*Добавляем к крестику*/
  top:1rem;/*Добавляем к крестику*/
  right: 1rem;/*Добавляем к крестику*/
  z-index: 1;/*Добавляем к крестику*/

  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  --weight: 3px;
  --aa: 1px;
  /* anti-aliasing */
  --color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent calc(50% - var(--weight) - var(--aa)), var(--color) calc(50% - var(--weight)), var(--color) calc(50% + var(--weight)), transparent calc(50% + var(--weight) + var(--aa))), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent calc(50% - var(--weight) - var(--aa)), var(--color) calc(50% - var(--weight)), var(--color) calc(50% + var(--weight)), transparent calc(50% + var(--weight) + var(--aa)));
}
<!-- Portfolio1 -->
  <section id="portfolio1" class="two">

<div class="container">

  <header>
    <h2>Натяжные потолки</h2>
  </header>

  <p>Натяжные потолки - без стыков, швов и перепадов. Огромная палитра цветов и фактур.<br /> Наша команда
    профессионалов с многолетним стажем работы и огромным опытом - выполнит монтаж любой сложности в кратчайшие
    сроки. Использование профессионального
    инструмента обеспечивает чистый монтаж.<br /> Мы всегда готовы удивлять своих клиентов приятными скидками и
    акциями. Потолки Моло - это ваш правильный выбор.</p>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-4 col-12-mobile">

      <article class="item">
        <div class="close"></div>
        <a href="images/foto102.jpg" class="image fit">
          
          <img src="images/foto102.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>

          <header>
            <h3>Световые линии зигзаг на натяжном потолке</h3>
          </header>
      </article>
      <article class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/foto101.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <header>
          <h3>Трековое освещение на натяжном потолке</h3>
        </header>
      </article>
      <!--<article class="item">
                                    <a href="#" class="image fit"><img src="images/foto107.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    <header>
                                        <h3>Фото 7</h3>
                                    </header>
                                </article>-->




Вот так получилось. Уже хоть на фото попал, а то у меня было вокруг да около. Фото вверху

сделал изменения в ответе

с таким исполнением крестик сам по себе, можете что угодно на него навешивать, любые события
